# WSO2 Passing Windows NTLM authentication through ESB to .NET REST Data Service

Tags: iis, wcf-data-services, windows-authentication, wso2, esb

I have a .NET data service that resides on a windows server using basic authentication.  I have a custom proxy service set up in the ESB that points to my data service endpoint.  When I access the data service through Internet Explorer it asks for my credentials as expected and everything works fine.  However when I change the IIS to use Windows Integrated authentication for the data service I don't get a response.  How do I get the ESB to handle the authentication handshake between my data service and the browser or any other application calling the data service?

Answer (score 0):

"Windows Integrated authentication" do you mean kerberos ?. if so http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/12/kerberos-authentication-with-wso2-esb.html might help you.

Regards,
/Nuwan